# WPF Binding listview checkboxes to display as favorites

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

In my current WPF MVVM setup I have a treeview which is populated from a directory of files/folders. Including sub folders and files. However I want to implement a simple 'favorites' feature. Meaning I can click the checkbox by each file in the treeview and then when I click the main 'checkbox in the UI' it will filter the list to only display the 'favorties'.

It may seem like a general question, but how do I go about doing this? Organizing and binding up the UI?

I've posted the solution 'visual studio 2013' to my dropbox for anyone who is willing to help me out.

### [Download Dropbox Files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8s5nvgzskrssk8n/Varo_forum_favorites.zip?dl=0)

My guess is adding another ObservableCollection which stores the nodes checked as favorties, and the original treeview nodes. So when the user enables the main checkbox it loads the favorties list to the ui, when unchecked it reloads the treeview.

```
// collection of nodes which you see in the image below on the left    
public ObservableCollection<INode> DisplayNodes //nodes displayed in UI
public ObservableCollection<INode> FavoriteNodes //nodes marked as favorites
public ObservableCollection<INode> StructureNodes //system node structure
```

pseudo function below

```
public void PopulateUI()
{
    DisplayNodes.Clear();

    if (showFavorites.isChecked)
    {
        DisplayNodes = FavoriteNodes;//nodes displayed in UI
    }else{
        DisplayNodes = StructureNodes;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to download your project from work, but I can give you some general guidance on this.

This can be done by modifying your INode implementations (FileNode, DirectoryNode etc) to include a `IsFavorite` bool property.

In your view model, add a property called `FavoritesEnabled`. In the setter of that property, you can replace your `RootNodes` observable collection, with a collection of filtered INodes.

```
private bool favoritesEnabled;
public bool FavoritesEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return this.favoritesEnabled;
    }
    set
    {
        this.favoritesEnabled = value;
        this.RootNodes = value == true
            ? new ObservableCollection(this.FilterFavorites)
            : new ObservableCollection(this.CreateRootNodes);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<INode> FilterFavorites()
{
    List<INode> nodes = new List<INode>();
    foreach(DirectoryNode directory in this.RootNodes.OfType<DirectoryNode>())
    {
        nodes.AddRange(this.filterFavorites(nodes, directory.Children.OfType<DirectoryNode>());
        nodes.AddRange(this.RootNodes.OfType<FileNode>().Where(item => item.IsFavorite);
    }
}

private List<INode> FilterFavorites(List<INode> filteredResults, IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> directories)
{
    // Recursively look up all favorites.
    foreach(DirectoryNode directory in directories)
    {
        filteredResults.AddRange(FilterFavorites(filteredResults, directory));
    }
        nodes.AddRange(this.RootNodes.OfType<FileNode>().Where(item => item.IsFavorite);

    return filteredResults;
}
```

Then you just update your data templates for the treeview so that the checkbox for each item is data-bound to the IsFavorite property on the INode implementations.

The recursive code above is more or less psuedo because i can't test it without bringing down your project. It should help get you started in the right direction. With this approach, you can continue to maintain just a single collection. You'll need to move the creation of your `RootNodes` property out of your constructor and into a reusable method. This way, as you toggle the favorite property in the view model, your `RootNodes` collection generate either a favorite collection, or an "all" collection.

If you're not able to get it working, i can grab your stuff tonight from home and give a proper example.

Comment: alright, your guidance definitely helps clear things up, just what i was looking for.

Comment: i implemented step one which was the 'favoritesEnabled' part to the viewmodel. rather simple. now onto the next step of actually populating the data.

Comment: You should be able to just add a checkbox to your data templates, and data bind it the the IsFavorite property on your models. That will let you toggle favorite files/folders and store that data in your existing collection of nodes that can be filtered.